# How does the Entity Framework differ from a normal ORM?

Tags: entity-framework, orm

Like the title says: Why do people including Microsoft say ORM is only a feature in the Entity Framework? What is different between it and a typical ORM? For me, EDM is same as XMl mapping from nHibernate. Why does Microsoft say this is not same?

Comment: @halfdan - You have right ! For me it seems like marketing like in Apple "great, fabulous" etc. ;)

Answer (score 6):

The one thing that sets apart Entity Framework from most (if not all) other ORM's out there is the fact that is has three layers - a **storage** model which is the physical database model (tables, views etc.), a **conceptual** model which represents your objects in your app, and a mapping layer between those two.

You can do mappings in EF where a single .NET object maps onto several database tables, and other things. You can also map object inheritance hierarchies into several ways of representing those in database tables.

NHibernate can do something similar, definitely in the inheritance area (not sure about the mapping one .NET object to multiple tables).

Almost all other ORM's are just simply a more or less glorified 1:1 mapping of database tables into .NET objects - no mapping and modelling capabilities.

Answer (score 4):

It is really a marketing but based on real effort. Entity framework is an ORM but in the same time it is MS strategic platform for data access. Entity framework is base layer for many others advanced APIs like WCF Data Services, WCF RIA Services, ASP.NET Dynamic Data, etc. These APIs works with other data sources as well but they are mostly developed for EF and used with EF. That is the difference MS is pointing.

My opinion is that it is nice to see that MS has a vision and a strategy but in the same time I would like to see just working and powerful ORM instead of marketing statements presenting me features which I don't need.

Comment: This was that what I was thinking. This is big Microsoft marketing. But can You tell more about that APIs "...they are mostly developed for EF and used with EF" I didn't know it that WCF "should" use EF.